# PostgreSQL didn't install on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-11.04

On a new copy of Ubuntu 11.04 server I am trying to install PostgreSQL server by `apt-get install postgresql`. But in the end of installation log I saw:

```
Error: could not create default cluster. Please create it manually with

  pg_createcluster 8.4 main --start
```

When I ran this command I saw this message:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
LC_ALL = (unset),
LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
```

And no PostgreSQL server started :(

What I need to do to become happy on this?

Comment: What's the output of "locale -a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This lines are helped me:

```
echo 'LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
echo 'LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"' >> /etc/default/locale
```

Answer (score 6):

**The accepted answer didn't help me**; if there are others like me please read below.

I traced the problem to `pg_upgradecluster` explicitly unsetting `LC_ALL`. This made Perl fail whichever way I was playing with the other environment variables.

So what I did is that I simply commented line 352 in `/usr/bin/pg_upgradecluster`:

```
#delete $ENV{'LC_ALL'};
```

This did the trick. Of course, this will only work if you're an average Joe with en_US.UTF-8 in all clusters and don't use any fancy encodings that you need to preserve.

Comment: Same issue on Ubuntu 14.04 while upgrading from 9.1 to 9.3. The accepted answer didn't help me either. After commenting the line upgrade run just fine. Thanks for this suggestion.

Comment: Wow, this saved a lot of headaches for me today! Thanks a lot! I would like to know though why is pg_upgradecluster unsetting LC_ALL.

Answer (score 2):

The current environment variables have effect as well. Use the command

```
locale
```

to see what is seen by Postgres, and update using `export` statements, e.g.:

```
export LANGUAGE="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Luckily for you this is an issue I had to look up my notes on, but you asked it in September 2011.

Check these links - Enlist the help of Google Translate

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Perl_warning_Setting_locale_failed_unter_Debian

http://www.thomas-krenn.com/de/wiki/Locales_unter_Ubuntu_konfigurieren

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale#List_current_settings